# Trying to find strings from a huge file and replace the result with another string

Tags: python, regex

Below is my code -

```
import tarfile
import os
import sys
import re

script, bak = sys.argv
bakfile = str(bak)
currentwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
file_to_work = tarfile.open(name=currentwd+"/"+bakfile, mode="r")
file_to_work.extractall()

currentwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
with open(currentwd+"/onedb.xml", "r") as file:
    f = file.read()
    words = re.findall(r'{ssha}_\w*?=', f)
    re.sub(words,r'string_to_replace',f)
```

I used `tarfile` module and extracted a gzfile, from the extracted files, picked onedb.xml. Used regex to find the strings and that was successful.

Now when I try to replace searched strings using `re.sub`, I get the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "preset.py", line 16, in <module>
    re.sub(words,r'string_to_replace',f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 232, in _compile
    p = _cache.get(cachekey)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: `words = re.findall(r'{ssha}_\w*?=', f)` returns a python `list`. You are passing that `list` to the `re.sub` function as your pattern. That is bound to lead to errors.

Comment: @Abdou, thanks to you.  Any suggestion to fix this?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are trying to replace, but if you are trying replace all the elements of `words` then you may try: `re.sub('|'.join(words),r'string_to_replace',f)`.

Comment: @Abdou, Exactly, the list `word` contains the below element.

`['{ssha}_HAAAAFOjyEqQXgnRvmuGP1EHUmCNQRWbI5rmKj1eZxI=', '{ssha}_HAAAANdJSESs1eKu838XKoHfO5xGfz49aKviPRQzmdI=']`

 They are present in the onedb file as well. I want to replace the strings in the onedb file with a different string. Sorry if I confuse you.

Comment: `f = re.sub('|'.join(words),r'string_to_replace',f)` should take care of that.

Comment: @Abdou, didn't work. I may be doing something very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use all in one Expression:

```
re.sub(r'{ssha}_\w*?=', r'string_to_replace', f)
```

Comment: Tried this. Since the file is huge, the script just sits and not sure what is going on behind the scene. @stovfl